# How to disable HTTP 1.0 protocol in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I've seen multiple resources explaining how to disable HTTP 1.0 on Apache, Nginx, IIS etc, but none for Tomcat. Could anyone advice how I can disable HTTP 1.0 protocol in Tomcat 9?

Answer (score 0):

According to [apache tomcat official site](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Connector_Comparison), the [http2 protocol implementation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http2.html) is based on http11 connector. Specific disable function have I found none.

Comment: do you reckon using mod_rewrite to deny http 1.0 requests is a feasible alternative?